# Different output of du and df

Tags: disk-usage

Ok, here's the issue which is totally confusing to me:

```
df -h
Dateisystem          Größe Benut  Verf Ben% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda2             3,8G  1,5G  2,2G  41% /
/dev/sda1             122M   13M  103M  11% /boot
tmpfs                1014M     0 1014M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1            1016M  866M  150M  86% /srv
```

However:

```
du -hs /srv
55M     /srv
```

Just for information:

```
mount | grep srv
/dev/sdb1 on /srv type xfs (rw)
```

The 86% gave me a warning email (which is intended) after which I deleted ~800MB of files under `/srv`. This was a few hours ago.

Using `du`, I get what I consider the correct amount of data on that partition. However, `df` doesn't seem to get that. Why? (This is somewhat annoying, because I still get regular warning emails based on that output.)

Not sure if that's important, but I'm on a server using CentOS release 5.11 (Final).

Comment: If the files are still open by an application the disk space won't be freed until the process ends.  Find out what's using /srv and stop/restart them.

Comment: Ok, that was it. One of the files was a logfile and I didn't restart the service that used it - didn't know I needed to. Thanks a lot for the quick and correct answer!! :) Should I close/delete this question? If so, how?

Comment: did the 800MB of files you deleted include large logfiles and/or other open files?  these files wont actually be deleted until they are closed (this often means restarting the syslogd or whatever program still has them open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` counts the file system allocated blocks, `du` use the size information of each files. 
A difference can have many cause:

1) Unlinked (deleted) files that are still open by application.  `lsof +aL1 <filesystem>` will helps you to identfy the processes.

2) Files beneath mount points hidden to `du`. `debugfs` can helps you.

```
$ sudo debugfs 
debugfs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
debugfs:  open /dev/<the / file system  device>
debugfs:  cd /boot
debugfs:  ls -l 
 1966081   40755 (2)      0      0    4096 26-May-2016 16:28 .
      2   40555 (2)      0      0    4096 11-May-2016 10:43 ..
 1974291  100644 (1)      0      0       0 26-May-2016 16:28 bob   <---<<< /boot/bob is hidden by /boot fs
```

3) [Sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) that looks bigger than the reality. non allocated blocks are not counted by `df` but they are counted in the file size.

Note that Hard links do not fools `du`

Answer (score 0):

If files are still open by an application the disk space won't be freed until the process ends. Find out what's using `/srv` and stop/restart them